# Can we list all groups whose elements has order at most 3 and precisely 4 cyclic subgroups of order 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can we list all groups whose elements has order at most 3 and precisely 4 cyclic subgroups of order 3?

One example is the abelian group $C_3\times C_3$. I want to know if there is any other group which satisfies this property or can we prove that $C_3\times C_3$ is the only group.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Two further examples are $A_4$ and the generalized dihedral group of order $18$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the only groups with those properties:
$C_{3}\times C_{3}\;, A_{4},\; D(C_{3}\times C_{3})$ (the generalized dihedral of $C_{3}\times C_{3})$.

*Proof.* Let $G$ be such group. Note that the number of the subgroups of order $3$ is half of the number of the elements of order $3$. So $G$ has exactly $8$ elements of order $3$.

Case 1) [$\mathrm{exp}(G)=3$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group#:%7E:text=Definition,%2C%20depending%20on%20the%20convention).
In this case, we see that $|G|=9$, and easily we get that $G\cong C_{3}\times C_{3}$.

Case 2) $\pi(G)=\{2,3\}$.
In this case, it is proved that groups with the property $\pi(G)=\{2,3\}$ are isomorphic to one of the following groups:
a) $C_{2}^{2k}\rtimes C_{3}$, which is a Frobenius group.
b) $C_{3}^{k}\rtimes C_{2}$, which is a Frobenius group.

By some simple observations, we get that among these groups, only $A_{4}\cong (C_{2}\times C_{2})\rtimes C_{3}$ and $D(C_{3}\times C_{3})\cong (C_{3}\times C_{3})\rtimes C_{2}$ have $8$ elements of order $3$.

Comment: Remind me again what $\pi(G)$ is, please; I can't find it anywhere. I know it has something to do with the primes that divide the orders of elements . . .

Comment: Please, also, provide a proof/link for the isomorphism claims of Case 2.

Comment: The last paragraph needs some elaboration too.

Comment: $\pi(G)$ has different definitions here and there, but the most common one is the set of the primes dividing $|G|$. And about the claims it is actually in the paper here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869391902719 . Thank you for the edits by the way. @Shaun

Comment: You're welcome. But are you sure they're there? What page(s)? (I had a brief look but didn't see them.)

Comment: PDF wise page two. Journal wise page 389. The Theorem.

Comment: Thank you. I'm impressed (+1)